# Como fazer para não ter um miss click na próxima tela?

Tags: java, android

Estou tendo um pequeno problema numa aplicação de um Quiz. quando o usuário clica no botão vem a próxima pergunta. coloquei um delay de 1 sec. No entanto, se o usuário clicar 2x no botão dentro deste delay de 1 sec, quando abrir a próxima pergunta ela já vai ser clicada.

```
     private void ResetTempo() {
     mCountDownTimer.cancel();
     mTimeLeft = StartTempo;
     try {
        new Thread().sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     mCountDownTimer.start();
     }

           r4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            r4.setEnabled(false);
            ResetTempo();         

            updatePerguntasoma(r.nextInt(mPerguntasomaLenght));
                    r4.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Consegues ser mais especifico ou mostrar algum exemplo?

Comment: Tenho um quiz com  uma pergunta e quatro respostas, 4 botoes.Se o usuário dá 2 clicks na primeira resposta... a primeira e a segunda pergunta são respondidas pelo button. mostrei o codigo, pq quero um sleep de 1 sec.. então o usuario da 2 clicks, a pergunta espera 1 sec e é responda, abre a segunda pergunta e é respondida(apos 1 sec também) também pelo duplo clic na primeira pergunta. Não consigo explicar de maneira mais clara.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que se você desabilitar o botão enquanto estiver no delay já resolva.

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Bom! Pensei que fosse uma boa ideia! Funciona, mas o botão fica inativo! fiz com que o botão ficasse true novamente depois do delay! mas se eu der um duplo click! o botão é acionado, desabilitado, espera-se 1 segundo,  vai para a próxima pergunta, o botão é habilitado novamente, e(aquele click fica "esperando" o botão habilitar, e automaticamente a segunda pergunta já é respondida pelo mesmo botão)

Comment: Então coloque uma condição dentro do evento de click para ir para a próxima pergunta somente se o usuário responder a questão.